# python no lambda - sort dictionary on value

Tags: python, function, sorting, dictionary, key-value

To sort a dictionary on values, all the answers I found use a lambda. Is it possible to use a function? I can't seem to get the values passed correctly.

```
sales = {
    'north': 2,
    'south': 6,
    'east': 8,
    'west': 7,
}

def get_value(collection,key):    # substitue for lambda x: x[1]
    return collection.get(key)

print(sales)
#sort_sales = sorted(sales.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])   # uses lambda
sort_sales = sorted(sales.items(), get_value( sales,sales.items() ) )
print(sort_sales)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at what `sales.items()` gives you. Based on that you can do:

```
def get_value(item):
    return item[1]

sorted(sales.items(), key=get_value)
```

Returns

```
[('north', 2), ('south', 6), ('west', 7), ('east', 8)]
```

Comment: Wow, it snapped into focus. I didn't understand what sales.items actually returned. And that makes the [1] in the function clear. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of defining your own `get_value`, you can also use `operator.itemgetter(1)`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of `lambda x: x[1]` is

```
def get_value(x):
    return x[1]
```

Generally, you can turn the lambda argument list into a function argument list and the lambda expression into a `return` statement, and that will suffice for any non-capturing lambda. For capturing lambdas, you'll need to make a nested function that explicitly captures the variables you want.

```
# (Non-specific example)
def get_value(foo):
    def _function(x):
        return x[foo]

# If we assume we have a variable foo defined as
foo = 1

# Then the two are roughly equivalent
fn1 = get_value(foo)
fn2 = lambda x: x[foo]
```

Comment: Thanks, Silvio, for breaking that down. For some reason I was stumped on why [1] thinking it had to do with the first-most in the sorted order. And I didn't see how it changed to 2nd.  It is the 1th value in each element of the collection.items() list.